# PHP soap extension not loading

Tags: php, iis, soap

I am trying to set up a php website that uses soap on IIS and I cannot get the soap extension to load.  I have use phpinfo() and can see that it is loading the correct php.ini file, however soap is not loaded.  I have uncommented the extension=php_soap.dll, I have the extension_dir set correctly, I have even tried to load the extension directly from a path like extension=c:\php\php_soap.dll.  None of these attempts have been fruitful.

I have also tried to enable other extensions that I don't need just to see if they will enable and none of them will.

Pulling my hair out now, hoping someone here can give me a hand.

Comment: Did you try `zend_extension=c:\php\php_soap.dll` or `zend_extension_ts=c:\php\php_soap.dll`?

Comment: Also try to find out has your php install was built with `--enable-soap` and php_soap.dll exists

Comment: @Baldrs I just tried those and they did not work.  How do I know if it was built with the --enable-soap extension?  The php_soap.dll does exist.

Comment: Found the problem.  I had a corrupt php.ini file.  I started from scratch and now its working.